# Using Glass on a multilingual sitecore site

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I'm building a multilingual Sitecore site and using Glass Mapper as the ORM, but running into an issue when the sitecore item doesn't exist in a particular language.

Rather than having a null model being passed into the view which I could check, I'm getting:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'foo'.

This exception is happening on the placeholder line rather than in the particular view.

Specifying a model against for each rendering seems to solve the issue for renderings where a datasource has been specified (although doing this results in a model having an instance but every property is blank). But if the data source is the regular context item I get the error:

Could not locate item containing model definition. Model path: /sitecore/layout/Models/foo

Any ideas?

Comment: Sitecore doesn't really want to render a view without a model, that's why it calls it with the parent's model, because it didn't have a language version and `Glass.Mapper` model binder returned null.
I suggest you to intercept this case in the Sitecore MVC pipeline, detect the case where you won't have a proper model, and simply return an `EmptyResult`.